Define a map from $\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 V$ to kernel of projection to $\bigwedge^6 V$
For some representation $V$ and exterior power $\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 V$, we have a projection map $$p: \bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 \rightarrow \bigwedge^6 V.$$
I want to define a map $$\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 V \rightarrow \operatorname{ker}(p).$$
This would give me something along the lines of $$[a \wedge b \wedge c + a \wedge b \wedge d] \wedge [d \wedge e \wedge f] \mapsto [a \wedge b \wedge d] \wedge [d \wedge e \wedge f].$$
Is it possible to define such a map? Assuming $V$ is a $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ representation, is it possible to do so in a $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ equivariant way?

The first map you describe is not a projection unless you have already situated the second space in the first. However the second map could easily be a projection you just need to choose an appropriate complement to $\ker(p)$.

The third expression you write is not a map into this kernel. If anything it is one of the few elements not in the kernel that you have written (assuming your first map is the obvious one of "remove the brackets")

Ah yes I'm an idiot - I just edited so that the expression actually is in the kernel. And yes the map is "remove the brackets"

Hints Once you have an embedding $\bigwedge^6 V \hookrightarrow \bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 V$, consider the map ${\bf 1}_V - p$. Also, recall that $W \otimes W = \bigodot^2 W \oplus \bigwedge^2 W$.
